# error deploying noauth_local_webserver

Tags: php

I am getting following error while deploying php project to google app engine

```
2015-09-04 06:26:27 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', '-u', 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--oauth2_credential_file=C:\\Users\\chandra/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens', 'update', 'I:\\phpapp\\helloworld']"
06:26 AM Application: rgukt2k14; version: 1
06:26 AM Host: appengine.google.com
06:26 AM 
Starting update of app: rgukt2k14, version: 1
06:26 AM Getting current resource limits.
Your browser has been opened to visit:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fappengine.admin+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&response_type=code&client_id=550516889912.apps.googleusercontent.com&access_type=offline

If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this
application with the command-line parameter 

--noauth_local_webserver
```

after entering user id and password ,its not deploying its redirecting to local url

Comment: To me it is not obvious that this is an error. What does that page say?

Comment: after entering user id and password ,its not deploying its redirecting to local url

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I resolved that in this way:

Try to use console and navigate to google appengine folder; then write:

appcfg.py update c:\pathToYourProject --noauth_local_webserver

That solved my nightmare and now it's working directly from app engine, luckily!

Just, I noticed that you have a PHP project. Try to do the same, but instead make a call of appcfg.php (probably that must be the correct name; whatsoever it is, just run the appcfg update as said upper)